# not able to select count with case condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the two tables:

*user_groups*

```
id    name    created_user
1     gn1     3
2     gn2     3
```

*user_group_has_users*

```
group_id    user_id
2           5
2           6
```

I want to count the users per group and an output similar this:

```
id    name    user_count
2     gn2     2
1     gn1     0
```

I tried this query

```
select g.*,
       count(cg.user_id) as user_count
from user_groups as g
left join user_group_has_users as cg on cg.user_group_id = g.id
where g.created_user = 3
```

But it only returns one row. I do not understand why this happening.
Please help me on this.

Comment: I don't understand what that output is counting.

Comment: it counting the total number of user, that belongs to the group.

Comment: Try with this, add after your query group by cg.user_group_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT g.* ,COUNT(cg.user_id) AS user_count 
FROM user_groups g 
LEFT JOIN user_group_has_users cg ON cg.group_id = g.id 
WHERE  g.created_user = 3 
GROUP BY g.id 
ORDER BY user_count DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join with where condition is nothing but inner join. You may want as

```
select 
ug.id,
ug.name,
count(ughu.user_id) as user_count 
from user_groups ug 
left join user_groups_has_users ughu on ughu.group_id = ug.id 
and ug.created_user = 3 
group by ug.id
order by user_count desc ;
```

If you still want to filter the data with the `created_user = 3` then use inner join and move the condition to `where clause`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with aggregates and JOINs.  In some cases the numbers are inflated.

See if this works for you:

```
select  g.*, 
      ( SELECT  count(*)
            FROM  user_group_has_users
            WHERE  user_group_id = g.id 
      ) AS user_count
    from  user_groups as g
    where  g.created_user = 3
```